# Welches Verb muss man benutzen? "Kommen nach" oder "Kommen"?

Tags: separable-verb

I want to ask a person: "Why are you coming to Berlin? As a tourist or for job?"
Is it right to ask:

1. Kommen Sie Berlin als Tourist oder beruflich?
2. Kommen Sie als Tourist **nach** Berlin oder beruflich?

Which one is the right answer?

I think the first one, because nachkommen is meant "später kommen, hinter jemandem hergehen, herfahren" in the Duden Wörterbuch.

Comment: Es ist "beruflich", ohne ü. Hauptworte u. Satzanfang groß.

Comment: Entschuldigung! Ich bin so Neuling im deutsch Sprache!! :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be translated quite literally, though you have a small mistake in your thoughts.

> Do you come *to* Berlin as a tourist or for job?
>   Kommen Sie *nach* Berlin als Tourist oder beruflich?
>   Kommen Sie als Tourist *nach* Berlin oder beruflich?
>   Kommen Sie als Tourist oder beruflich *nach* Berlin?

The *nach* here doesn't come from *nachkommen*, but from *to*. Due to the liberties that the German language has in word ordering,
 all 3 of my given translations are correct and I wouldn't even say that one is better or more frequently used than the others.

If it were *nachkommen*, the sentence would be

> Kommen Sie Berlin *nach* als Tourist oder beruflich?

meaning something like

> Do you *follow after* Berlin as a tourist or for job?

making no sense, as you recognized correctly.

EDIT: I just recognized again the title of you question. That's exactly the point: *kommen nach* is not equal to *nachkommen*.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ich habe eine Wette gemacht und Unglücklicherweise ich war unrecht!!

Comment: Du warst nah dran! Übrigens: Ich habe eine Wette gemacht/abgeschlossen und unglücklicherweise *war ich im Unrecht*. ;)

Comment: :))) Haha ... Ich war wieder unrecht!! Deutsch Sprache ist sehr süß zu lernen!

Comment: Oder "hatte ich nicht Recht" oder "hatte ich Unrecht", was für mich natürlicher klingt als "war ich im Unrecht". Letzteres ist eher gehobene Sprache. Das Wort "Unrecht" generell ist eher selten im alltäglichen Gebrauch anzutreffen.

Answer (score 2):

The following sentences are all correct and have absolutely the same meaning:

> Kommen Sie **nach Berlin** als Tourist oder beruflich?
>    Kommen Sie als Tourist oder beruflich **nach Berlin**?
>    Kommen Sie als Tourist **nach Berlin**, oder beruflich?

But the last one sounds as if you originally just wanted to ask "Kommen Sie als Tourist nach Berlin?" and decided later to add "oder beruflich?".

Note that the verb of all these sentences is *kommen*, nicht *nachkommen*. Also pay attention to the fact that **nach Berlin** is not separated. In this case the word *nach* is a preposition to *Berlin*: **nach Berlin** = **to Berlin**

In contrast to that, the *nach* in *nachkommen* is not a preposition but a (separable) part of the verb *nachkommen*; in finite forms of the verb this part moves to the end of the sentences. Like in the following examples:

> Peter kommt seiner Reisegruppe später **nach**.
>    Kommt Peter seiner Reisegruppe später **nach**?

And of course, you can combine the preposition *nach* and the verb *nachkommen* in the same sentences:

> **Nach Berlin** kommt Peter später **nach**.
>    Peter kommt später **nach Berlin** **nach**.

Comment: Vielen Dank Min-soo!

Answer (score 0):

2 is correct.

1 is incorrect because *kommen* with a destination cannot be used without a preposition.

In sentence #2 the verb is *kommen*, not *nachkommen*. Because in that sentence, *nach* is a preposition to *Berlin*, so it's not part of the verb.

If you wanted to use *nachkommen*, it would be:

> *Kommen Sie Berlin als Tourist oder beruflich nach?

which would be correct grammar but wrong semantically because as you correctly stated nachkommen means "to come after" (also "to comply").